# How (why) definition of Namespace by ServiceContract affects functionality

Tags: c#, wcf, wsdl

I have a ServiceContract like this:

```
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface IHttpsServer
  {
    [OperationContract] 
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    void Post(SomeEvent e);
  }
```

Event defined like this:

```
  [Serializable]
  [XmlType(Namespace = "")]
  public class SomeEvent 
  {
    [XmlAttribute("flag")]
    public bool m_bFlag;

    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string m_strName;
    ...
  }
```

This service is hosted by `ServiceHost` with 'BasicHttpBinding'.

What't I'm doing:

1. start web service
2. add reference to the running web service on the client app
3. start client and send SomeEvent to the server.

And at this point I have a problem - Post-function will be called, but SomeEvent is empty (all nullable fields are `null`).

But, if I an empty namespace to ServiceContrat (`[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]`), then it works fine. 
Why is this happens?

**Update:**

I've executed several checks any have strange results:

1. When a namespace define by ServiceContract and by SomeEvent (`[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://anynamespace")]` and `[XmlType(Namespace = "http://othernamespace")]`), then it *works fine*.
2. When a namespace is defined by only by ServiceContract (`[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://anynamespace")]` and `[XmlType(Namespace = "")]`), then it *does not work*.
3. When there is an empty namespace defined by both (`[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]` and `[XmlType(Namespace = "")]`), then it *works fine*.
4. When there is an empty namespace by ServiceContract, but a namespace is define for SomeEvent (`[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]` and `[XmlType(Namespace = "http://othernamespace")]`), then it *works fine*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I suppose, I've found the reason of this behavior.

First of all I've implemented `IDispatchMessageInspector`. This gave me possibility to trace requests from the client. 
Requests from client are look like this:

```
+       request {<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://localhost/</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IHttpsServer/Post</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Post xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xml flag="true">
        <Name>John</Name>
      </xml>
    </Post>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>}  System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message {System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage}
```

After a while I've noticed, that there is a default namespace defined for `Post` node, and there is no namespace defined for 'xml' node. So, what we have is that `xml` in this example is a part of `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"` and not an empty namespace as it defined.

To check my suggestion I've generated client code and manually added an `XmlType` attribute to the declaration of the `SomeEvent`:

```
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(Namespace = "")]
```

After this change I've got the followed request:

```
+       request {<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <To s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">https://localhost/</To>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/IHttpsServer/Post</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Post xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <xml flag="true">
        <Name xmlns="">John</Name>
      </xml>
    </Post>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>}  System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message {System.ServiceModel.Channels.BufferedMessage}
```

(there is definition of the default namespace by the `Name` node).

And after that my service works fine.

*My suggestion on reason of the problem*:

In case, when I've defined empty namespace for the event `[XmlType(Namespace = "")]public class SomeEvent {...}` the attribute `XmlType` will be skipped while generation of the client code. And this places when a request will be sent, xml that describes the event is placed into namespace of the `ServiceContract`. After that WCF can't deserialize event.

*So there are two solutions of the the problem*:

1. Avoid usage of the event with empty namespace (see use-case 2).
2. Add partial class for event `[XmlType(Namespace = "")]public partial class SomeEvent {}`